# How to change index route depending on state

Tags: redux, react-router, react-redux

Let's say I have the following main React application, using `react-redux` and `react-router` (but not `react-router-redux` yet):

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={LoginRequiredPage}/>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/entries" component={ShowEntries} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
</Provider>
```

In my store I have the state `isLoggedIn` and I would like to change the component of `IndexRoute` to `ShowEntries` when `isLoggedIn` is true and back to `LoginRequiredPage` if it becomes false. I'm not sure how to achieve this, but can think of several ways:

1. use the react-redux `connect` method on `IndexRoute` to map `isLoggedIn` to a new value for its `component` property.
2. create a `Home` component, connect it to the store, switch out its child component depending on `isLoggedIn` and have `Home` as the new `IndexRoute` component

Which option is better or is there an even better solution?

I'd like the current view to change while the index route is active and the `isLoggedIn` state changes.

Comment: My answer is for the second option. You can't simply connect `Route` or `Router` to the Store, so you either need to provide a connected component via `component` prop of `Route`, or do some redirect magic directly in router configuration using the store you created earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to do that is to declare a component that would either return `ShowEntries` or `LoginRequiredPage` based on value of certain property of the Store:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Index}/>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/entries" component={ShowEntries} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
</Provider>
```

and

```
@connect(state => ({
  isLoggedIn: ... // <- place the correct value here
}))
class Index extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      isLoggedIn
    } = this.props;

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return <ShowEntries />
    } else {
      return <LoginRequiredPage />
    }
  }
}
```

---

Another way would be to check if the user has logged in per every route enter via `onEnter` prop, and redirect to certain route, but that means you'll evidently change the location a user sees in their browser. But if you're curious, check out [this tip](https://github.com/taxigy/til/blob/master/redux/react-router-action-on-enter.md).

Comment: what if you want to fetch data in async call in onEnter hook. And I mean different data for each of the components(for instance using async-connect or something similar). How would you solve that?

Comment: That's a separate topic. But remember that, once component is connected, it will get updated (rendered) per every change of property of state that it has in its props via connect. There will be two stages: we don't know if user is logged in (null), then we know if the user is logged in (true) or not (false). Setting new values and rendering this and that according to them would be the solution.